# Cannot use SDL_gfxPrimitive

Tags: c, sdl, gfx

I´m trying to use the filledCircleRGBA function from the _gfxPrimitive lib from SDL2, but it says 'fatal error:SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h: No such file or directory

I have both includes and I use -lSDL2 and -lSDL2_gfx on the command line

```
#include <SDL.h>    
#include <SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h>

int main() {
    SDL_Window* g_pWindow = NULL;
    filledCircleRGBA(g_pWindow, 2, 4, 4, 255, 255, 255, 255);

return 0;
}
```

Why can´t I use _gfxPrimitives functionalities? I have the -dev SDL2 installed, so it should have all the libs

Comment: The includes should probably be `#include<SDL2/SDL.h>` and `#include<SDL2/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h>`. The linker flags `-lSDL2_gfx` are not related to this error. Check that the file in question (`SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h`) actually exists on your system. It is also relevant how you installed the SDL2 package (which OS/distribution/package manager)

Comment: Guessing that you are on ubuntu, the file is in `libsdl2-gfx-dev`. Is it installed?

Answer (score 0):

Installed with SDL2 is `sdl2-config`, a program which you run with parameter `--cflags` or `--libs`. Pass the output of using either parameter to your compiler and linker, respectively. `--cflags` is particularly what you need, as it instructs the compiler to add the SDL2 include directory to your compiler's search path.